# How to install latest Kong chart with ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kubernetes-helm

I have a problem installing Helm chart for Kong and not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's a chart issue.

If I run:

```
helm upgrade kong stable/kong \
            --install \
            --set ingressController.enabled=true
```

Everything is installed but on the second run (and I would like to execute always same command in CI/CD) it fails because migraiton tasks have wrong password.

If I try to hardcode the password:

```
helm upgrade kong stable/kong \
            --install \
            --set ingressController.enabled=true,env.pg_password=<hardcoded-string>
```

It fails even on first try with failed password.

What is the expected way to deploy Kong as ingress controller in a continous manner?

## Edit 1

Versions:

```
rafal.wrzeszcz@devel0:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.6", GitCommit:"b1d75deca493a24a2f87eb1efde1a569e52fc8d9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-16T04:30:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
rafal.wrzeszcz@devel0:~$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

## Edit 2

`kong-postgres` proof of existance:

```
rafal.wrzeszcz@devel0:~$ kubectl get secret kong-postgresql -o yaml --namespace <my-namespace>
apiVersion: v1
data:
  postgresql-password: <base64-encoded-string>
…
```

Comment: You are using default pg from kong? Have you change the default password?

Comment: Yes, I use default PG from Kong chart. I tried doing `--set ingressController.enabled=true,env.pg_password=<some-hardcoded-string>` but then even first deploy doesn't run (says `password authentication failed for user "kong"`).

Comment: Default password is "kong", is it working?

Comment: It is **NOT** working, apparently. The jobs fail with the message as above.

Comment: You need to provide more details so I can try to reproduce it, for now I don't see any issues when executing for a second time `helm update kong stable/kong --install --set ingressController.enabled=true`.

Comment: It worked on my coleague's minikube cluster, but not in the AWS test cluster. What more details are needed?

Comment: Is secret `kong-postgresql` present, if you do `kubectl get secret kong-postgresql -o yaml` is key `postgresql-password` followed by the password?

Comment: Yes, both are present:

`$ kubectl get secret kong-postgresql -o yaml --namespace my-project
apiVersion: v1
data:
  postgresql-password: <base64-encoded-string>`